# Using .htaccess and mod_rewrite in a directory (not root)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site that sits in a directory on a domain:

```
http://www.example.com/site/
```

I also have an `.htaccess` file in `/site/` which has several rewrite rules. These rules work if all the files (including the .`htaccess` file) sit on the top-level of the domain: e.g., at www.example.com.

My `.htaccess` file looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^css/loader/\d+/([^/]+)(\?(.*))?$  /loader.php?t=css&c=$1
```

I need the rules to work within the directory but I can't seem to figure out it, can anyone please help?

Edit: figured it out, server was on Apache 1.2+ which uses the POSIX regex engine as opposed to the PCRE engine in Apache2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: figured it out, server was on Apache 1.2+ which uses the POSIX regex engine as opposed to the PCRE engine in Apache2.

Answer (score 1):

Change RewriteBase to `/site/` instead of `/`

Comment: I've tried that...it doesn't work. 

I need:

http://www.example.com/site/css/
to go to
http://www.example.com/site/loader.php

Comment: Also keep in mind that my .htaccess file must be in the /site directory...thanks for helping!

Comment: then try removing ^ from the request uri regexp, since ^ notes the beginning of url from the root. try using ^site/css

Answer (score 0):

Don’t change the base URL (remove the `RewriteBase` directive) and use a relative path in your substitution:

```
RewriteRule ^css/loader/\d+/([^/]+)$  loader.php?t=css&c=$1
```

Comment: @Calvin L: What URL do you to test your rule?